# Interstitial Ads Not Being Presented (IOS; Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, admob, interstitial

I'm trying to implement ads into my first app. I made banner ads work, however am currently stuck on interstitial ads.

I have it initiated in the App Delegate and plist and my code looks like this:

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit
import GoogleMobileAds

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    var interstitialAd: GADInterstitialAd?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        interstitialSetup()
    }

    func interstitialSetup() {
        GADInterstitialAd.load(withAdUnitID: "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX", request: GADRequest(), completionHandler: { [self] ad, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Failed to load interstitial ad with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                print("Load successful.")
            }
            self.interstitialAd = ad
            self.interstitialAd?.fullScreenContentDelegate = self
        }
        )
    }

    func interstitialPresent() {
        self.interstitialAd?.present(fromRootViewController: self)
    }
    
}

extension GameViewController: GADFullScreenContentDelegate {

    func adDidDismissFullScreenContent(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd) {
      print("Ad did dismiss full screen content.")
    }

    func ad(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd, didFailToPresentFullScreenContentWithError error: Error) {
      print("Ad did fail to present full screen content.")
    }

    func adDidPresentFullScreenContent(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd) {
      print("Ad did present full screen content.")
    }
    
}
```

The `interstitialPresent()` function is currently called when a 'Start Button' node is pushed in my Game Scene.

Can someone please assist with what's wrong here?

Thanks guys.

Comment: Aren't you supposed to set an ad delegate to self or something?

Comment: Like interstitialAd.delegate = self in `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: I have `self.interstitialAd?.fullScreenContentDelegate = self` in my interstitialSetup function, which is called in viewDidLoad. @ElTomato

Comment: I see.  It looks like you have done it correctly according to AMob doc except that I don't know if your interstitial isn't really working.

Comment: I thought so too, which is why it's become so frustrating. Hopefully someone is able to find something we're overlooking. Thanks for taking the time @ElTomato

Comment: Code looks fine (I am presenting interstitial ads with the same code without problems). Could you check adUnitId? It should be "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910" for testing purposes

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out the issue. My GameViewController transitions to an SKView in the viewDidLoad function and an interstitial ad cannot be presented in an SKView, only a UIView.

Can anyone assist with me with how I can transition from an SKView back to a UIView in my GameScene, so I can present the interstitial ad after the game ends?

Comment: you are trying to use StackOverflow as a forum-like community. Stackoverflow does not work this way - it is FAQ style database of "Question->Answer" pairs. I bet nobody will look for your new questions asked in a answer so they will stay unanswered. I suggest you to [take a tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [check help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to get familiar with what Stackoverflow is and how to use it. If you have new question then [create new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)